# Aligning google maps marker images to prevent overlap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I need to put users on map and at some zoom levels the images might overlap, like in first image, I know that most solutions recommend to group them as in second image, but is there a way to nicely align them as in the 3rd image ?

Default position of my markers:

[image: default aligning (not great)]

Some solution that I often see:

[image: some solution (not great)]

Ideal position of markers:

[image: ideal position]

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the lat-long values of the marker pointer. If they are too close then they will overlap or you can take a smaller pointer image according to your zoom level so that markers are displayed separately without overlapping.

Comment: It is more than that, at certain zoom levels they might not overlap, but they overlap once you zoom out. So markers position should adjust based on zoom too. Sounds complicated but I expected this to be a common problem.

Comment: yes it will happen that way only beacause when you zoom in the map, you get more space on screen for a less area(lat-longs expand) and vive-versa when you zoom out the area contracts and lat-longs move closer hence your markers. You can use different images at different zoom levels, it will solve your problem.